# Javascript: why is 2 && 3 gives 3?

Tags: javascript

I was reading some tricky javascript output question and found that

```
console.log(2 && 3) is 3
```

There is no explanation for the same. Shouldn't it be `true`?, as value of both the numbers being non zero should be type casted as `true`

Comment: `(a && b) == (a ? b : a)` and `(a || b) == (a ? a : b)`.

Comment: `&&` gives the first `false` starting from the very left. If none, it'll return the last one

Comment: In javascript only flow control statements like `if`,`while` do implicit typecasting to boolean

Comment: @Anirudha Nope. `&&` and `||` also do implicit typecasting *for flow control*, [at least since ES5](https://es5.github.io/#x11.11).

Comment: @Rhymoid no they dont.. am qouting this in the doc you shared here..its mentioned that " The value produced by a && or || operator is not necessarily of type Boolean. The value produced will always be the value of one of the two operand".. later if this expression is inside a flow control statement, it will be type casted via `toBookean` ..this behaviour is also mentioned in the doc you shared under if condition section

Answer (score 2):

It's just the way the language works. It is well documented.

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> Logical AND (expr1 && expr2) Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false;
>   otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, &&
>   returns true if both operands can be converted to true; otherwise,
>   returns false.